# Type Error: Undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a tic tac toe game, and though the game is functional, when one player wins, the debugger pops up if they win using certain spaces. I get a type error saying that 'O' can't be set of undefined. Also in my console a negative number will print out for the elementIndex when a player wins by clicking only on certain spaces.

It appears to be coming from this line in my game.win function:

```
game.winCombos[elementIndex][unitIndex] = game.currentPlayerTurn;
```

---

```js
var gameboard = {

  initialize: function() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        var unit = $("<div class='unit'></div>");
        unit.appendTo('#gameboard');
      }
    }
    console.log(100);
    gameboard.addId();
  },

  addId: function() {
    var id = 1
    $('.unit').each(function() {
      $(this).attr('id', id);
      id++;
    });
  }
};

var players = {

  firstPlayer: {
    token: 'X'
  },
  secondPlayer: {
    token: 'O'
  }
};

var game = {

    newGame: function() {
      game.winCombos = game.clone();
      game.currentPlayerTurn = players.firstPlayer.token;
      gameboard.initialize();
      game.displayToken();
    },

    currentPlayerTurn: players.firstPlayer.token,

    displayToken: function() {
      $('.unit').click(function() {
        if (game.currentPlayerTurn === 'X' && !$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
          $(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('unit').text("X");
          game.currentPlayerTurn = players.secondPlayer.token;
        } else if (game.currentPlayerTurn === 'O' && !$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
          $(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('unit').text("O");
          game.currentPlayerTurn = players.firstPlayer.token;
        }
        game.win($(this));
      })
    },

    win: function(div) {

      game.winCombos.forEach(function(element) {
        element.forEach(function(unitIndex) {
          if (unitIndex.toString() === div.attr('id').toString()) {
            var elementIndex = game.winCombos.indexOf(element);
            var unitIndex = element.indexOf(unitIndex);
            game.winCombos[elementIndex][unitIndex] = game.currentPlayerTurn;
          }
        })

        var counter = 0

        for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
          if (element[i] === game.currentPlayerTurn) {
            counter++;
          }

          if (counter === 3) {
            counter = 0;
            game.gameOver(true);

          }

        }
      })
    },

    gameOver: function(bool) {
      if (bool === undefined) {
        bool = false;
      }
      $('.unit').remove();
      $('.selected').remove();
      game.newGame();
    },

    winCombos: [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [3, 6, 9],
      [1, 5, 9],
      [3, 5, 7]
    ],

    clone: function() {
      return [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [3, 6, 9],
        [1, 5, 9],
        [3, 5, 7]
      ]
    }
```

Comment: at the line where you think the error is occurring, try adding a breakpoint or console.log(...) to see what the values of `unitIndex` and `elementIndex` are. then work backwards to figure out why it has that value.

Comment: yeah I do that the line directly above where it says the error is. It outputs the correct information up until someone wins, and only if they win on certain spaces. Then it says it is undefined and the index that gets printed out for element is -1. So something is going on there but I'm stumped as to what

Comment: You have all the code, use the debugger to figure out when it gets set to -1.

Comment: The *clone* function looks redundant, you don't need a function just to get a static array.

Comment: if you're getting a `-1` there it means that the `game.winCombos.indexOf()` method did not find the thing it is looking for, so if you look at what that is, you should be able to work that out. Further, you don't actually manually need to get those indices because the `forEach` methods can supply them to you. e.g. `someArray.forEach(function(item, index) { ... });` the second arg for the callback is the index of the element.

Comment: Use the debugger to single-step through the script, then you should be able to see where the bad value is coming from and why.

Comment: Dymos and Barmar, thank you. Just getting rid of the variables I made and putting the index in the function as an argument solved the problem